# Rotate Pin Orientation on MapKit Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, rotation, mapkit

I am trying to rotate an UIImage that is set to an Annotation that is placed on a MapKit.

I want the image that is set on that Annotation to be rotated with a specific degree.

I have already tried a few methods, but they didn't work.

Can somebody help me?

[image]

[image: This is what I tried to do, but didn't work]

Comment: Upload your code, not as image

Comment: I am new in this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should replace

`annotationView.transform.rotated(by:CGFloat(M_PI_4))`

by this:

`annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi/4.0))`

or:

`annotationView.transform = annotationView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/4.0))`

#### Update

If you only want the image to rotate, you can put the image in a UIImageView, and add the UIImageView as a subview to the MKAnnotationView. Below is a simple example about how to do it(Do not use directly, it's not completely).

```
class CustomMKAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        imageView?.image = nil
    }

    func updateImge(image: UIImage?) {
        guard let aImage = image else {
            return
        }

        if imageView == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: aImage)
            if imageView != nil {
                frame = imageView!.frame
                addSubview(imageView!)
            }
        } else {
            imageView!.image = aImage
            frame = imageView!.frame
        }
    }
}
```

and in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`:

```
annotationView.updateImge(image: UIImage(named: "car.png"))
annotationView.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi/4.0))
```

Comment: It worked, but the title and subtile turn too and I only want the image to rotate

Comment: @MirunaGroza , I update my answer, explain how to rotate the image only.